# Error while pushing JSON data from Kafka using Kafka connect to InfluxDB

Tags: json, apache-kafka, influxdb, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to push `JSON` data from `Kafka` to `InfluxDB` using `Kafka-connect`.
Kafka version- 2.2.0, using Kafka-connect came along the apache-kafka.

Worker properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
rest.port=8083
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.partitions=50
config.storage.topic=connect-configs1
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.partitions=10
offset.storage.file.filename=/data/md0/kafka/data/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins
consumer.max.poll.records=10000
```

On starting the REST curl command and data push, logs are throwing the following exception:

```
[2019-11-14 09:41:33,294] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=FlinkAggsInfluxDBSink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:558)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct
        at io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.writeRecordsToDB(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:230)
        at io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.put(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:112)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-11-14 09:41:33,295] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=FlinkAggsInfluxDBSink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct
        at io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.writeRecordsToDB(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:230)
        at io.confluent.influxdb.sink.InfluxDBSinkTask.put(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:112)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
        ... 10 more
[2019-11-14 09:41:33,295] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=FlinkAggsInfluxDBSink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the error says it wants to `cast to org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct`, then you need schemas as part of that data, not plain JSON.

Therefore, you can either

1. producer Avro data to the topic, and use the AvroConverter
2. update your producer to use `{"schema": ..., "payload": ... }` formatted JSON with `value.converter.schemas.enable=true`
3. find [another InfluxDB sink](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/influx.html) that does support plain JSON.